# List of data.frame's to individual excel worksheets - R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I have a list of data.frame's that I would like to output to their own worksheets in excel. I can easily save a single data frame to it's own excel file but I'm not sure how to save multiple data frames to the their own worksheet within the same excel file.

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(sortedTable[1], "c:/mydata.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Specify sheet name for each list element.

```
library(xlsx)
file <- paste("usarrests.xlsx", sep = "")
write.xlsx(USArrests, file, sheetName = "Sheet1") 
write.xlsx(USArrests, file, sheetName = "Sheet2", append = TRUE)
```

Second approach as suggested by @flodel, would be to use `addDataFrame`. This is more or less an example from the help page of the said function.

```
file <- paste("usarrests.xlsx", sep="")
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet1")
sheet2 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet2")

addDataFrame(USArrests, sheet = sheet1)
addDataFrame(USArrests * 2, sheet = sheet2)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = file)
```

Assuming you have a list of data.frames and a list of sheet names, you can use them pair-wise.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
datas <- list(USArrests, USArrests * 2)
sheetnames <- paste0("Sheet", seq_along(datas)) # or names(datas) if provided
sheets <- lapply(sheetnames, createSheet, wb = wb)
void <- Map(addDataFrame, datas, sheets)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = file)
```

Comment: @what was `void<-Map(addDataFrame, datas, sheets)` for ? Does not look like after mapping the void variable was not used to saveworkbook. is this step required ?

Comment: @user5249203 no, `Map` does not save file, just prepares the data for `saveWorkbook`.

Comment: createSheet didn't work for me (perhaps cause its 3 years on) I had to use addWorksheet

Answer (score 9):

The following code works perfectly, which is from:https://rpubs.com/gbganalyst/RdatatoExcelworkbook

```
packages <- c("openxlsx", "readxl", "magrittr", "purrr", "ggplot2")

if (!require(install.load)) {
  install.packages("install.load")
}
install.load::install_load(packages)

list_of_mydata

write.xlsx(list_of_mydata, "Excel workbook.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is a really good, simple answer for this question and would probably be upvoted more if you edited it slightly. You're requiring four additional packages to be installed and loaded that are not necessary for this answer. You only need `openxlsx`. I would recommend changing this answer to something much more simplified: `library(openxlsx); write.xlsx(list_of_mydata, "Excel workbook.xlsx")`.

Comment: It's also worth noting the `write.xlsx` will use the names from your list as the sheet names in the output Excel file.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the solution with openxlsx:

```
## create data;
dataframes <- split(iris, iris$Species)

# create workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()

#Iterate the same way as PavoDive, slightly different (creating an anonymous function inside Map())
Map(function(data, nameofsheet){     

    addWorksheet(wb, nameofsheet)
    writeData(wb, nameofsheet, data)

}, dataframes, names(dataframes))

## Save workbook to excel file 
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "file.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

.. however, openxlsx is also able to use it's function openxlsx::write.xlsx for this, so you can just give the object with your list of dataframes and the filepath, and openxlsx is smart enough to create the list as sheets within the xlsx-file. The code I post here with Map() is if you want to format the sheets in a specific way.

Answer (score 5):

lets say your list of data frames is called `Lst` and that the workbook you want to save to is called `wb.xlsx`. Then you can use:

```
library(xlsx)
counter <- 1
for (i in length(Lst)){
   write.xlsx(x=Lst[[i]],file="wb.xlsx",sheetName=paste("sheet",counter,sep=""),append=T)
   counter <- counter + 1
}
```

G

Comment: I see it now, I was editing my answer, left for a while and came back without checking if there was any update. My bad.

Comment: Is the `counter` really needed if you start your loop with `for (i in 1:length(Lst))`? Seems like a `while loop` set up for a `for loop`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest solution is still missing. Using the `writexl` package you can write a list of data frames easily:

```
list_of_dfs <- list(iris, iris)

writexl::write_xlsx(list_of_dfs, "output.xlsx")
```

Also, if you have a *named* list then those names become the sheet names:

```
names(list_of_dfs) <- c("a", "b")

writexl::write_xlsx(list_of_dfs, "output.xlsx")
```

---

Alternatively, the `rio` package allows for more export control and the syntax and handling of named lists is similar:

```
rio::export(list_of_dfs, "output.xlsx")
```

You can also easily output them to their own workbooks as well.