# Loop to export multiple dataframes in r to Excel and Name Each Sheet

Tags: r, excel, loops, export

I have 2 data frames that I would like to export to Excel, with each dataframe on a different worksheet, and to title each sheet.

I have tried the following with `write.xlsx` .

Here is the list of my 2 data frames followed by the title I would like to give them in the new Excel workbook:

```
list_of_datasets <- list(pivot.diagnosis, stat.pivot.quarter)
wk.title <- c("9-STD Durations", "10-STD Clinical Categories")
```

This is the loop I have tried:

```
for (i in length(list_of_datasets)) {
  write.xlsx(list_of_datasets[i], file = "Trial.xlsx", 
           sheetName = wk.title[i], 
           append = TRUE)
}
```

**PROBLEM:** This only outputs the *last* data frame (i.e. `stat.pivot.quarter`) to the Trial.xlsx spreadsheet. `Append = TRUE` is there, so I would think it would append *with each iteration* of the loop, but it's not. **It seems like `append = T` isn't working**

Any leads appreciated!

Comment: There are a couple of packages that write to excel, which one are you using?

Comment: Also, for a list, you are going to need to use `write.xlsx(list_of_datasets[[i]], file = "Trial.xlsx"`

Comment: Potential duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524472/list-of-data-frames-to-individual-excel-worksheets-r) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: To clarify, my code was for _only_ 2 data frames, but I am really interested in doing this for _many_ data frames. Particularly interested in _custom naming_ each worksheet as the loop exports each data frame. Thx

Answer (score 0):

[writexl](https://docs.ropensci.org/writexl/) is a lightweight package that would serve you well here.

```
writexl::write_xlsx(
  list("sheetname1" = dataframe1, "sheetname2" = dataframe2),
  path = "path/to/save/to.xlsx"
)
```

Comment: This is not helpful. I was using this package already - see my code above. I need a loop for many data frames, and be able to loop through and place unique worksheet names for each iteration/data frame.